# Simplest representation of the inverse of an identity matrix plus a positive matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a $n\times n$ identity matrix $I$ and a $n\times k$ matrix $U$.
Then can we representate $(I+UU^T)^{-1}$ **without** involving any inverse term, such as $U^{-1}$? Specifically，I hope $(I+UU^T)^{-1}$ can be represented as sum of polynomial terms of $UU^T$ or $(I+UU^T)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another answer with a different trick. If this is not what you want either, then maybe you should be more specific on the requirements in your question.

The matrix $M:=I+UU^T$ has at most $d:=\min(n, k+1)$ distinct eigenvalues (because $UU^T$ has the eigenvalue 0 with multiplicity at least $n-k$). Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial (which can be taken of degree $\leq d$) such that $p(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ for each of these eigenvalues. Then, $p(M)=M^{-1}$; that is, $M^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $M$ of degree at most $d$ (and hence also a polynomial in $UU^T$). This is true because the two matrices have the same basis of eigenvectors and associated eigenvalues. Note that this polynomial depends on the matrix $M$ itself (via its eigenvalues).

(The same trick works also for non-symmetric matrices, but one needs to use Hermite interpolation with multiplicities equal to the algebraic multiplicities of each eigenvalue --- see for instance chapter 1 of Higham's *Functions of matrices*)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Sherman--Morrison--Woodbury formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity): 
$$
(A+UCV)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}.
$$

Comment: I hope $(I+UU^T)^{-1}$ can be represented as sum of polynomial terms of $U$ or $(I+U)$. SMW formula is not helpful for me. But still thanks.